# Norm of a Positive Operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras

For a positive operator $A\in B(\mathcal{H})$ on a complex Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$, I want to prove that $\|A\|=\sup\{\lambda: \lambda \in \sigma(A)\}$, where $\sigma(A)$ is the spectrum of $A$.

So, in effect, I need to show that the spectral radius for a positive operator on a complex Hilbert space is equal to it's norm. I began by showing that the spectral radius $\rho(T)$ of any self-adjoint operator is less than or equal to $\|T\|$. I am stuck in the reverse inequality.

Comment: Since there are a number of equivalent definitions of "positive operators" you should say what particular definition you are using. Also, some context would be nice...  i.e. why are you interested in this statement (a proof of which can surely be found in any book on operator theory)?

Comment: Since all the definitions are equivalent, any one would do. In particular, $A\in B(\mathcal{H})$ is positve if $<Ax,x>\geq 0$ for every $x\in \mathcal{H}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In context of the above comment, it suffices to show that the spectral radius $\rho(T)=\|T\|$ for a self-adjoint operator $T\in B(\mathcal{H})$.
That $\rho(T)\leq \|T\|$ is a trivial observation. For the reverse inequality, we need to show that either $\lambda$ or $-\lambda$ is in $\sigma(T)$,  where $\lambda= \|T\|$. This is same as showing that $\lambda I-T$ or $-\lambda I-T$ is not invertible. To this end, we prove that $T^2-\lambda^2I$ is not invertible, for if it is not then at least one of its factors $\lambda I-T$ or $-\lambda I-T$ is not invertible.

The proof is by the method of contradiction. Suppose, if possible, $T^2-\lambda^2I$ is invertible.Then there exists $\alpha >0$ such that $$\alpha I\leq(T^2-\lambda^2I)^*(T^2-\lambda^2I)=(T^2-\lambda^2I)^2$$.

Now,\begin{multline*}
0\leq <(\lambda^2I-T^2)^2x,x>= \|(\lambda^2I-T^2)x\|^2\leq\|\lambda^2I-T^2\|\|(\lambda^2I-T^2)x\|^2\\
\leq 2\lambda^2\|(\lambda^2I-T^2)x\|^2\leq 2\lambda^2<(\lambda^2I-T^2)x,x>.
\end{multline*}
This yields
$$2\lambda^2(\lambda^2I-T^2)\geq (\lambda^2I-T^2)^2\geq\alpha I$$ which implies 
$$(2\lambda^4-\alpha)I\geq 2\lambda^2T^2$$.
Observe that 
$$(2\lambda^4-\alpha)\|x\|^2=<(2\lambda^4-\alpha)Ix,x>\geq<(2\lambda^2T^2)x,x>\geq2\lambda^2\|Tx\|^2$$ for each $x\in \mathcal{H}$

This means that $\|Tx\|\leq \sqrt{\lambda^2-\frac{\alpha}{2\lambda^2}}$ which contradicts the assumption that $\|T\|=\lambda$. This proves that $T^2-\lambda^2I$ is not invertible which in turn completes the proof.

Answer (score 0):

The spectral radius of $T$ is $\lim_n \|T^{n}\|^{1/n}$. However, $\|T^{2}\|=\|T\|^{2}$ for any selfadjoint $T$. This is because
$$
       \|T\|^{2}=\sup_{\|x\|=1}\|Tx\|^{2}=\sup_{\|x\|=1}(T^{2}x,x) \le \sup_{\|x\|=1}\|T^{2}x\|\|x\|=\|T^{2}\|.
$$
On the other hand,
$$
                  \|T^{2}\|\le \|T\|\|T\|=\|T\|^{2}.
$$
You get the final result by noticing that $\|T^{2^{n}}\|^{1/2^{n}}=\|T\|$.